# Is this operator positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

When is the operator $\begin{pmatrix} S^*S & \sqrt{2} S \\ \sqrt{2}S^* & S^*S \end{pmatrix}$ positive, where $S \in B(H)$ is of norm $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "positive"?

Comment: self-adjoint with spectrum contained in the non-negative reals.

Comment: Just a thought, not sure if it will work: If $A$ is this operator, then $A$ is self-adjoint and $\|A\| \leq 2$, so it suffices to find a $t\geq 2$ such that $\|t-A\| \leq t$. Since $\|S^{\ast}S\| = 2$, perhaps one can do this by computing $\langle (t-A)(x,y),(x,y)\rangle$. I tried this, but the computation gets hairy - perhaps you can give it a shot.

Comment: My answer below shows that it is not true in general. What kind of condition are you thinking about, since you are asking "**When** is the operator ... positive?"?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true in general. To see this, set
$$
S=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
\sqrt{2} & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$
Then
$$
S^{\ast}S=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \sqrt{2}\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
\sqrt{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$
so that your matrix takes the form
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$
Note that the "middle" submatrix is
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 2\\
2 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$$
which has determinant $0\cdot2-2\cdot2=-4<0$, so that $B$ is not
positive semidefinite. Thus, $A$ is not positive semidefinite either.

Comment: Thank you very much.